# How is view state saved/restored in Android?

Tags: android

I have this class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int mClicks = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView clicksText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clicksText);
        final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mClicks++;
                clicksText.setText(mClicks + " clicks");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Isn't it supposed to save view state at onSaveInstanceState and restore it at `onCreate`? I click the button a couple times and rotate the device to find the UI in the exact same state as the view XML defines. I don't expect `mClicks` to be restored as that is my job, not the framework's but the TextView should hold the previous X clicks! value. Am i wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `freezesText`

[image: freezeText]

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText

Comment: Awesome property, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default `onSaveInstanceState` saves the `EditText` text (what the user writes) but does not save `TextView` text because it is supposed that it won't change by default. If you want to save that, you need to explicity do it in you `onSaveInstanceState` method

Comment: Seeing as it has an id, it came to my mind that it would save the text value. Do you have any reference to back this up?